# How to define axes if all rotation axes pass through the same number of atoms?

Tags: symmetry, group-theory

I was wondering how one can define the axes for a molecule with several equal axes of rotation, all of which pass through the same atom. I know that the $z$-axis is usually defined as the principal axis, or the axis passing through the most atoms if none are equal. But in the case of, say, the $D_{2h}$ molecule below (assuming all R are the same), how do you define the axes? All 3 axes of rotation pass through only one atom, the central Cu.

[image]

Comment: What axes do you mean in "define the axes"? The principal one? If so, then you should already know the answer as you mentioned the point group.

Comment: What's to define? The rotation axes? We don't define them; we just find them. Or do you want to know where to put the $z$ axis? It doesn't matter.

Comment: In this molecule you can put the Z axis in any of three orthogonal directions  for the $C_2$ axes  and then choose one to make this the principal axis. When you look at the point group this will be based on just one of these axes ( which can vary between different textbooks) and so you need to check the notation say $\sigma(z, y) $ is the same as you get. If not move the principal axis and try again. Frequently, Z is chosen to point out of the plane of a molecule if it has one.

Comment: In response to andselisk, how do I know the principal one in this case since they're all c2? Finding the rotation axes is clearly straightforward, but my question was how I assign which of them is the z axis and hence the principal in this particular case?

Comment: And while I understand Ivan Neretin saying it doesn't matter, this is in the context of revision for an exam where almost all the past paper questions on this require you to show the axes

Comment: @atbm While often the assignment of the point group may be formalized in a flow diagram like the one on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_symmetry#Point_groups_and_permutation-inversion_groups) maybe there are previous exams / is a reasoning in your lecture notes why one of the three $C_2$ axes conventionally gains seniority. You may find _a kind of counting_ the $C_2$ axes by primes, though: $C'_2, C''_2$, etc. (e.g., https://symotter.org/tutorial/benzene)